# How to scale CoreNLP + Flask?

Tags: python, flask, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to use CoreNLP on production so it should be scalable enough. (5000 requests between 9am to 5pm)

I am using Python wrapper **pycorenlp** and using **Flask** framework as API an endpoint.

This Flask API endpoint is hosted on Elastic Beanstalk (AWS).
Reason: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/deploying/

I know it's possible to run the Stanford CoreNLP server multithreaded-ly.
*But is this enough?* *Should I be running multiple coreNLP servers?*

**What are the best practices to make this combination scalable enough?**
*I am assuming that coreNLP server should be running on the same server where Flask endpoint is hosted.*

Comment: 5000 requests over 8 hours is a very, very small load -- you should be able to handle this amount of requests on a laptop. Do you have a specific problem you've encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Even a single-threaded CoreNLP should have no problem handling this amount of requests. For example, I am currently running PoS tagging and NER on average length news articles. This takes up to a few seconds per request. Some models, e.g. coreference resolution, are much slower than others- make sure you are not running models you don't need by setting (for example) `-annotators=pos,lemma`.

Comment: I will be using sentiment model only. Load is not distributed evenly between 9am to 5pm because it is a chatbot. Between 10am to 12pm load is maximum and I want a system which is robust and scalable because number of users count is going to increase rapidly in coming months.

Comment: To answer the bold part of your question, the combination you have is already *scalable enough*. Let's do some maths. Depending on the models used, CoreNLP can process hundreds to tens of thousands of words per core per second (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/memory-time.html). If you are building a chat bot, your documents will be short, maybe tens of words each. This gives us a throughput of at least 10 documents per second per core, or 36k documents per hour. You can spin up more threads or run more instances behind a load balancer. Don't optimise prematurely.